# Rails 3.1 won't lazy load when trying something like this: user.posts.class #=>Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lazy-loading

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**In irb:**

```
> u = User.first
 => #<xxxxx>
> u.posts.class
 => Array
```

**My env:**

```
$ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p312 
$rails --version
--version
Rails 3.1.0
```

I remember that almost all relation query return an ActiveRecord::Relation in rails3;

What is wrong?

ps: I need to get the "klass" from the ActiveRecord::Relation object;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

davidb is correct about the has_many, but I assume you want the class without hitting the db. Use this:

```
User.first.posts.proxy_reflection.klass
```

(Disclaimer: Uses internal ActiveRecord methods and probably won't work if `Post` uses STI)

Answer (score 0):

You get the associated object in a 1..1 relation or in a 1..n relation from the side of the object wihich `belongs_to` another but not from the side that may have more than one associated Object. In that case its irrelevant if there are zero, one, two,... 100 Objects associated because the behavior shouldnt differ based on the count of associated objects.

So noting is wrong with your association.

```
u.posts.first.class #will return the associated class
```

Answer (score 0):

Find, first, all and last methods of active record will query the database directly instead of returning ActiveRecord::Relation object. You should try the following,

```
> klass = User.where("id=1").class
=> ActiveRecord::Relation
```

Note that console uses inspect method to display the output interactively.
Reference: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html